# Masstransit job service consumer concurrency limited to 2 request per minute

Tags: masstransit

I'm testing out Masstransit's sweet JobConsumer setup based on [JobConsumersSample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-JobConsumers). When I run locally with masstransit/rabbitmq image everything works great, the jobs are run respecting the configured concurrency limit. But when I try it against a real RabbitMQ installation in k8s it will process 1 job in the first minute and 2/minute after that very consistently. So obviously the issue is with my RabbitMQ setup but I don't know where to start. Any suggestions?

RabbitMQ version is 3.9.16 with rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange V3.9.0

[image]

I set up my ConsumerDefinition set up like this:

I don't think the issue is with my Masstransit setup but just in case:

```
   public class ExtractDocumentJobConsumerConfiguration : ConsumerDefinition<ExtractDocumentJobConsumer>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
      IConsumerConfigurator<ExtractDocumentJobConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
        {
            consumerConfigurator.Options<JobOptions<ExtractDocument>>(options =>
                options
                    .SetRetry(r => r.Interval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
                    .SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
                    .SetConcurrentJobLimit(20));
        }
    }
```

and this in my Program.cs

```
 builder.Services
                .AddMassTransit(
                    x =>
                    {
                        x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

                        x.AddConsumer<ExtractDocumentJobConsumer, ExtractDocumentJobConsumerConfiguration>();
                        //.Endpoint(e => e.Name = "extraction-job-queue");

                        x.AddConsumer<TrackAnalysisJobConsumer>();

                        x.AddSagaRepository<JobSaga>().InMemoryRepository();
                        x.AddSagaRepository<JobTypeSaga>().InMemoryRepository();
                        x.AddSagaRepository<JobAttemptSaga>().InMemoryRepository();

                        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

                        x.UsingRabbitMq(
                            (context, cfg) =>
                            {
                                cfg.Host(
                                    rabbitMQConfiguration.HostName,
                                    rabbitMQConfiguration.VirtualHost,
                                    h =>
                                    {
                                        h.Username(rabbitMQConfiguration.UserName);
                                        h.Password(rabbitMQConfiguration.Password);
                                    });

                                cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

                                var options = new ServiceInstanceOptions()
                                    .SetEndpointNameFormatter(context.GetService<IEndpointNameFormatter>() ?? KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);

                                cfg.ServiceInstance(
                                    options,
                                    instance =>
                                    {
                                        instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints(
                                            js =>
                                            {
                                                js.SagaPartitionCount = 1;
                                                js.FinalizeCompleted = true;
                                                js.ConfigureSagaRepositories(context);
                                            });
                                        //instance.InstanceEndpointConfigurator.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 20;
                                        instance.ConfigureEndpoints(
                                            context,
                                            f => f.Include<ExtractDocumentJobConsumer>());
                                    });

                                // Configure the remaining consumers
                                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                            });
                    });

            builder.Services
              .AddOptions<MassTransitHostOptions>()
              .Configure(
                  options =>
                  {
                      options.WaitUntilStarted = true;
                      options.StartTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
                      options.StopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
                  });
```

I had to comment out the `.Enpoint(e => e.Name = "extraction-job-queue")` or else it would give me an error saying the endpoint already existed.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the log (set level to DEBUG), specifically the message traffic between the sagas to determine why it isn't working as expected.

Comment: Thanks Chris, big fan of your videos BTW.  I see in the logs that as soon as the first job I start getting .JobService.JobSlotUnavailable and this continues until the first job completes and then it shows JobSlotAllocated and the next job is attempted. I don't see this same behavior when running locally though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what was wrong but I reset everything in RabbitMQ and started fresh and it started working.